Plane angle subtended by a segment at a point such that the line joining the point to the segment is not perpendicular to it
I am studying a chapter on Gauss's Law from Concepts of Physics - Volume 2 by HC Verma. There is a discussion about the notion of a solid angle in the chapter. While going through it, I encountered a point which I could not understand. Note the last (emphasized) line of the following:

Consider a plane angle subtended at a point $O$ by a small line segment $\Delta l$ (figure 30.7a). Suppose, the line joining $O$ to the middle point of $\Delta l$ is perpendicular to $\Delta l$. As the segment is small, we can approximately write
$\Delta \theta = \frac{\Delta l}{r}$.
As $\Delta l$ gets smaller, the approximation becomes better. Now suppose, the line joining $O$ to $\Delta l$ is not perpendicular to $\Delta l$ (figure 30.7b). Suppose, this line makes an angle $\alpha$ with the perpendicular to $\Delta l$. The angle subtended by $\Delta l$ at $O$ is
$\Delta \theta = \frac{\Delta l \cos\alpha}{r}$.

I am not sure as to why $\Delta \theta$ should be equal to what it is. I redrew the figure myself and tried to comprehend it. Here's what I achieved. 
It is to be actually shown that $GE = \Delta l \cos\alpha$.
Any clarification would be appreciated.

A circle of radius $r$ has a circumference $2\pi r$. If you draw two rays from the center, you cut out a piece of the circumference. The length of the piece is $l$. The angle $\theta$ is defined as $l/r$. This is a good way to represent a fraction of a circle.
For a small $\theta$, you can approximate $l$ with an isosceles triangle. If $\alpha$ is not $0$, the side of the triangle is too long, and you have to figure out the right length.
if $\Delta \theta$ is small, AGC is close to $90^o$. GD $<<$ GC.
GC $\approx l/2 cos(\alpha)$

I don't really get what you mean by "approximating $\Delta l$  with an equilateral triangle".

Sorry. isosceles. I edited it.
